# gcloud beta dataflow missing documentation on parameters

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, gcloud, dataflow

When I try to run the following:

```
gcloud beta dataflow jobs run $JOB_NAME \
--region $GCP_REGION \
--gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/PubSub_to_BigQuery \
--network $VPC_NAME \
--subnetwork regions/$GCP_REGION/subnetworks/$VPC_SUBNETWORK \
--staging-location gs://$GCP_PROJECT_ID-assoc-history-dataflow \
--worker-machine-type n1-standard-1 \
--parameters \
"inputTopic=$INPUT_TOPIC,\
outputTableSpec=$OUTPUT_SPEC,\ 
javascriptTextTransformGcsPath=$UDF_LOCATION,\
javascriptTextTransformFunctionName=myFunctionName"
```

gcloud gives me the following error:

> ERROR: (gcloud.beta.dataflow.jobs.run) INVALID_ARGUMENT: The template
>   parameters are invalid.
>   - '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.dataflow.v1beta3.InvalidTemplateParameters 
>   parameterViolations:
>     - description: Unrecognized parameter
>       parameter: |-
>         \
>         javascriptTextTransformGcsPath

It seems like `javascriptTextTransformGcsPath` is provided in the parameters according to the current documentation (https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided-utilities). I'm using the beta gcloud sdk to specify my VPC and subnet. Is there a link to documentation on how the JavaScript udf parameter has changed or is there another way to specify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using quotation marks (") in parameters. You can check the documentation. There is example:

```
gcloud dataflow jobs run JOB_NAME \
--gcs-location gs://dataflow-templates/latest/Bulk_Decompress_GCS_Files \
--parameters \
inputFilePattern=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/compressed/*.gz,\
outputDirectory=gs://YOUR_BUCKET_NAME/decompressed,\
outputFailureFile=OUTPUT_FAILURE_FILE_PATH
```

Just remove it and it should work.

Comment: it turns out that i had a space in the variable and the quotation marks did not like that. thank you!

Comment: Hi how do i add multiple values for a param like --parameters source=val1, val2